# Trying to reproduce some JavaScript code in PHP, variable overwrite issue, how to?

Tags: javascript, php, converters

I am trying to reproduce some js code in php. I'm not sure why i don't get the same results. I think js overtires some variables (`longitudeRange  and latitudeRange` to be more exact) that php doesn't.

the php `$range` doesn't have the same result as the js `range`.

any ideas?

```js
resp = encodeGeohash([34.2360444, -118.5284408]);
alert(resp);

function encodeGeohash (location) {
  var g_BASE32 = "0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz";
  var precision = 10;
  var latitudeRange = {
    min: -90,
    max: 90
  };
  var longitudeRange = {
    min: -180,
    max: 180
  };
  var hash = "";
  var hashVal = 0;
  var bits = 0;
  var even = 1;

  while (hash.length < precision) {
    var val = even ? location[1] : location[0];
    var range = even ? longitudeRange : latitudeRange;
    var mid = (range.min + range.max) / 2;

    if (val > mid) {
      hashVal = (hashVal << 1) + 1;
      range.min = mid;
    } else {
      hashVal = (hashVal << 1) + 0;
      range.max = mid;
    }

    even = !even;
    if (bits < 4) {
      bits++;
    } else {
      bits = 0;
      hash += g_BASE32[hashVal];
      hashVal = 0;
    }
  }

  return hash;
};
```

php code:

```
function geoHash($location)
{
    $g_BASE32       = "0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz";
    $precision      = 10;
    $latitudeRange  = ['min' => -90, 'max' => 90];
    $longitudeRange = ['min' => -180, 'max' => 180];
    $hash           = "";
    $hashVal        = 0;
    $bits           = 0;
    $even           = 1;

    while (strlen($hash) < $precision) {
        $val   = $even ? $location[1] : $location[0];
        $range = $even ? $longitudeRange : $latitudeRange;
        $mid   = ($range['min'] + $range['max']) / 2;

        var_dump($range);

        if ($val > $mid) {
            $hashVal      = ($hashVal << 1) + 1;
            $range['min'] = $mid;
        } else {
            $hashVal      = ($hashVal << 1) + 0;
            $range['max'] = $mid;
        }

        $even = !$even;

        if ($bits < 4) {
            $bits++;
        } else {
            $bits = 0;
            $hash .= $g_BASE32[$hashVal];
            $hashVal = 0;
        }
    }

    var_dump($hash);

    return $hash;
}

geoHash([34.2360444, -118.5284408]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign

```
var range = even ? longitudeRange : latitudeRange;
```

in javascript, range references an object. So, when you later assign

```
range.min = mid;
```

it actually changes the property of one of the objects referenced by either `longitudeRange` or `latitudeRange`.
Your php code in contrast uses an array in that place, which uses copy-on-write, i.e. when you assign `$range['min'] = $mid;` it does affect neither `$latitudeRange` nor `$longitudeRange`.
You can either use an object

```
<?php
function geoHash($location)
{
    $g_BASE32       = "0123456789bcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz";
    $precision      = 10;
    $latitudeRange  = (object)['min' => -90, 'max' => 90];
    $longitudeRange = (object)['min' => -180, 'max' => 180];
    $hash           = "";
    $hashVal        = 0;
    $bits           = 0;
    $even           = 1;

    while (strlen($hash) < $precision) {
        $val   = $even ? $location[1] : $location[0];
        $range = $even ? $longitudeRange : $latitudeRange;
        $mid   = ($range->min + $range->max) / 2;

        if ($val > $mid) {
            $hashVal      = ($hashVal << 1) + 1;
            $range->min = $mid;
        } else {
            $hashVal      = ($hashVal << 1) + 0;
            $range->max = $mid;
        }

        $even = !$even;

        if ($bits < 4) {
            $bits++;
        } else {
            $bits = 0;
            $hash .= $g_BASE32[$hashVal];
            $hashVal = 0;
        }
    }
    return $hash;
}

var_dump(geoHash([34.2360444, -118.5284408]));
```

or fiddle with [references in php](http://docs.php.net/references).

Comment: `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

Comment: Yes, I changed a bit more than just the explicit cast to object. But the code is working, see https://3v4l.org/VHrKW